# Infragistics Grid: Insert new field value for a read-only field

Tags: c#, .net, grid, infragistics

I have an Infragistics XamDataGrid where, for simplicity's sake, I have 2 Fields: **A** and **B**. Now **A** is read-only; I do this by setting Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Field.AllowEdit for **A** to *false* and set AllowEdit for **B** to true.

My goal is to be able to insert a new row into my grid under the following constraint: A new row must have values for both **A** and **B**. However, for this new row and all existing rows, **A** must be read-only and **B** must allow for editing.

Currently, if I want to insert a value for **A**, I must set AllowEdit for **A** to *true*. While this allows me to input a value for **A**, it also allows editing for existing values of **A** in the grid which is not what I want.

Therefore, I'm looking for settings along the lines of this: *AllowEditInGrid* and *AllowEditWhenInserting*.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.